# Python: How to insert block matrixes along diagonal of larger matrix

Tags: python, matrix, diagonal

I have generated a random symmetric 100 x 100 matrix. I have also generated a number of random 10 x 10 symmetric matrices. Now I want to insert these 10 blocks along the diagonal of the 100 x 100. How do I go about doing this?

I thought about getting the diagonal indices and then inserting as

```
B[diag1, diag2] = A
```

But I cannot seem to get the diagonal indices out to insert in the code.

Comment: Are you doing this with Numpy? If so, you should add the `numpy` tag to your question. You should also add a [mcve] of what you've tried, and clearly explain what's wrong with it.

Comment: Your matrix what is? an array of arrays, or a `numpy` instance? or something else?

Comment: in numpy you can access the blocks by `B[i:i+10, i:i+10]` (this is a 10x10 matrix, you can assign A to it)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `numpy` maybe this can help (works for symmetric and not symmetric matrices):

```
import numpy as np

# Your initial 100 x 100 matrix 
a = np.zeros((100, 100))


for i in range(10):
  # the 10 x 10 generated matrix with "random" number
  # I'm creating it with ones for checking if the code works 
  b = np.ones((10, 10)) * (i + 1)
  # The random version would be:
  #  b = np.random.rand(10, 10)
  # Diagonal insertion
  a[i*10:(i+1)*10,i*10:(i+1)*10] = b
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using numpy then we can write as another available solution

```
import numpy as np

x1 = np.eye(10)
A = np.block([
    [x1,np.random.rand(10,90)],
    [np.random.rand(10,10),x1,np.random.rand(10,80)],
    [np.random.rand(10,20),x1,np.random.rand(10,70)],
    [np.random.rand(10,30),x1,np.random.rand(10,60)],
    [np.random.rand(10,40),x1,np.random.rand(10,50)],
    [np.random.rand(10,50),x1,np.random.rand(10,40)],
    [np.random.rand(10,60),x1,np.random.rand(10,30)],
    [np.random.rand(10,70),x1,np.random.rand(10,20)],
    [np.random.rand(10,80),x1,np.random.rand(10,10)],
    [np.random.rand(10,90),x1],
    ])
print (A)
```

x1 is your small matrix and it can be any distribution, I used identity matrix for testing only.

Answer (score -1):

Doing this in a vectorized way would be ideal - and would, in theory, look something like this:

```
In [50]: a = np.ones((100,100)); b = np.ones((10,10))*2;

In [51]: np.diagonal(a)[:] = np.ravel(b)
```

But that doesn't work because `np.diagonal()` returns a read-only view of the underlying array:

```
In [51]: np.diagonal(a)[:] = np.ravel(b)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-ac0ada1b350d> in <module>()
----> 1 np.diagonal(a)[:] = np.ravel(b)

ValueError: assignment destination is read-only
```

Running `help(np.diagonal)` sheds some light on this behavior, and reveals that, at some point in the future, the vectorized expression above will work, because `np.diagonal()` will return a *mutable* slice of the array:

> In versions of NumPy prior to 1.7, this function always returned a new,
>   independent array containing a copy of the values in the diagonal.
>
> In NumPy 1.7 and 1.8, it continues to return a copy of the diagonal,
>   but depending on this fact is deprecated. Writing to the resulting
>   array continues to work as it used to, but a FutureWarning is issued.
>
> Starting in NumPy 1.9 it returns a read-only view on the original array.
>   Attempting to write to the resulting array will produce an error.
>
> In some future release, it will return a read/write view and writing to
>   the returned array will alter your original array.  The returned array
>   will have the same type as the input array.

However, Numpy (currently on version 1.13) still returns an *immutable* slice.

For anyone looking for a way to jump into Numpy and contribute, this would be a great first pull request.

**Edit: I interpreted the question as asking how to use the 100 entries from a given 10 x 10 matrix, and assign them to the 100 diagonal entries of the 100 x 100 matrix. Perhaps you meant setting 10 separate 10 x 10 blocks of the 100 x 100 matrix using 10 10x10 matrices. (In which case, it would be helpful to specify that you have 10 10x10 matrices - or include a picture.)**